# Gremlin Query (JSON Output) using tree

Tags: graph, gremlin, janusgraph

Query:

```
g.withSack(0).V().hasLabel('A').has('label_A','A').union(__.emit().repeat(sack(sum).by(constant(1)).in()),emit().repeat(sack(sum).by(constant(-1)).out())).project('level','properties').by(sack()).by(tree().by(valueMap().by(unfold())).unfold())
```

Output:

```
{
    "level": 1,
    "properties": {
        "key": {
            "label_A": "A"
            
        },
        "value": {
            "{label_A=A}": {}
        }
    }
},
{
    "level": 2,
    "properties": {
        "key": {
            "label_A": "A"
          
        },
        "value": {
            "{label_A=A}": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getting keys in json format but not values. Please suggest changes in query to acheive the values in json format.

Answer (score 0):

The `tree()` step returns a tree structure in the form of a `Map` of `Map` instances essentially so the output is about what you can expect. In this case, I wonder if you need to use `tree()` and could instead get by with `path()` as it seems like it accomplishes the same result without the added structure:

```
g.withSack(0).
  V().hasLabel('A').has('label_A','A').
  union(__.emit().repeat(sack(sum).by(constant(1)).in()),
        emit().repeat(sack(sum).by(constant(-1)).out())).
  project('level','properties').
    by(sack()).
    by(path().by(elementMap()))
```